# Ignoring the same filename in root and subdirectories

Tags: mercurial, pattern-matching, glob

In a Mac project, there are .DS_Store files at multiple levels, like so:

```
project/.DS_Store
project/subdir/.DS_Store
project/subdir/other_file.txt
project/.hgignore
```

When I use the following for a `.hgignore` file, the top-level .DS_Store doesn't get ignored. Is there any way to ignore both .DS_Store files with a single `glob` line in the `.hgignore` file? It seems like this should be easy, and adding another `.DS_Store` line feels clumsy.

```
syntax: glob

**/.DS_Store
```

The following works, but I prefer the readability of the `glob` syntax for ignore files:

```
syntax: regexp

.*\.DS_Store
```

Comment: The accepted answer is your best option, but note that you *can* mix glob and regexp syntax in a single `.hgignore` file. Any lines after `syntax:glob` will be interpreted as glob, until there's a line `syntax:regexp`, and vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `glob` expression, but don't limit it to being inside a folder, like this:

```
syntax:glob
.DS_Store
```

That will match any file with the exact name of `.DS_Store` anywhere in the repo.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think it was working, since `hg status` was showing files in subdirectories... that were already committed and modified. Once I removed them, I forgot to circle back and try the expression again. Thanks!